# How to include unreleased products in your portfolio?

Tags: resume, job-search, portfolio

Currently, we have built products that are not yet out in the public. However, they make up quite a huge and important chunk of my portfolio.. to demonstrate what I've done for the project.

I am a UX specialist and I need a lot of visuals to showcase what I've done. And I am not even sure if I can even mention about these unreleased products.

How do I handle this?

Comment: The question in your title and first part of your post is different from what you should be asking first: whether you can include these products at all. And that's not something we can answer: it depends on your company culture and its expectation of confidentiality.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I handle this?

Released or unreleased - get permission or don't use the actual site in your portfolio.

Consider using mockups or personal sites instead. (Many UX experts get permission to use non-functional draft versions hosted on their personal site. Sometimes identifying logos/text must be removed and replaced.)

Comment: This is the way to go.  Put your mockups on your laptop and use that to demo.